# Are there corner cases to this sort?

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to get back in to c++ and I've been doing a few exercises that includes sorting. I have to sort a simple array in descending order. As far as I remember the most simple sort goes like this :

```
for ( int i = 0; i < array_size; i++ ) {

    for ( int k = 0; k < i; k++ ) {

        if ( array[i] > array[k] ) {

            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[k];
            array[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And it works... But I was wondering if there are any corner cases where this would not work. I'm asking because as far as I looked I could not find anyone using this. Most of the examples I could find are similar to this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: This is bubble sort, the first sort to be taught. Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: It works everywhere, and your codes will be fine, yes. the reason that you don't looked this code(bubble-sort), maybe, there are many another sort functions that can be used simple and fast more than bubble sort.

Comment: *'I could not find anyone using this'* – because it is horribly inefficient...

Comment: there's funny videos that compare sort algorithms. you can search with "sort view" or "sort visualize" keyword online.

Comment: Nobody is using that since it is a slow algorithm and there is ready library solutions for that. Averyone just use `std::sort`.

Comment: Bubble sort only compares adjacent elements, so the code above is not bubble sort

Comment: Is the only question "are there any corner cases where this would not work"? If that is the case, consider compiling a working example with test cases and post on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Base cases

Let's check the trivial cases:

- `array_size = 0`. The outer loop exits immediately, and nothing changes, so this works.
- `array_size = 1`. The inner loop exits immediately, and nothing changes, so this works.

---

## Inductive step

Now assume that at some iteration `i` of the outer loop, the elements `0, 1, ..., i-1` are sorted. For instance, let `i = 3` and consider the following example:

```
array = 4, 2, 1, 3
```

Let's now walk through the inner loop. Swap the `k`th element with the `i`th element whenever the `i`th is larger.

```
k = 0:  array = 4, 2, 1, 3
k = 1:  array = 4, 3, 1, 2
k = 2:  array = 4, 3, 2, 1
```

It appears that the inner loop correctly sorts the array elements `0, 1, ..., i`.

Thus, at the end of iteration `i`, the array elements `0, 1, ..., i` are all sorted.

---

## Conclusion

The final iteration is at `i = array_size-1`. After this executes, the array elements `0, 1, ..., array_size-1` must all be sorted. But this exactly the entire `array`!

Comment: This whole logic is flawed because it is built on assumption that `i` and `k` may hold values up to `array_size` which is not true.

Comment: @VTT That can be easily fixed by replacing the `int` with a `size_t`. I think OP wasn't looking to sort arrays of size `[2^31, 2^32 - 1]` on 32-bit machines anyways... especially not with this algorithm!

Comment: @VTT No? The inductive step uses `array_size=4`, `i=3` and `k<=2`... Or did you mean that `int` can't hold all `size_t` values (in that case: It wasn't specified that `array_size` is of type `size_t`)?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq It can definitely be fixed or even completely rewritten using different algo to work much faster, but the question wasn't about those "fixed" variants. This answer simply is not applicable to the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

С++ uses `size_t` as a type large enough to hold size values while `int` variables may be insufficient. For example on typical 64 bit platform with 32 bit `int` it will have a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 so attempt to sort larger array won't work and potentially may cause signed overflow which is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Where in the question does it say that `array_size` is of type `size_t`? For all you know `array` is of a type with `operator[](int index)`...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Language allows arrays (or whatever entity is behind `array`) to be large enough. And that's exactly the corner case OP was asking about.